# Difficulties with more advanced javascript patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, libraries

I'm having a bit of trouble with a small Javascript library that I am creating for practice that mimics jQuery and other libraries. As of now it does not work. I'm very new to Javascript and to scripting in general as I have only started teaching myself, so chances are I'm simply missing something that would be obvious to most. I have tried searching for a solution, but I have not been able to find one, so I have resorted to asking about it myself.

This is the library itself:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
var document = window.document
var $m = function(obj) {
if (typeof obj === "object") {
    return obj
}
else {
    return document.getElementById(obj)
}

class: function(name){
    var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('*')
    var objects = []

    for (var q = 0 ; q < ele.length ; ++q){
    if (ele[q].className === name){
        objects.push(ele[q])
    }
    }
    return objects
}

s: function(){
    return this.style
}

window.$m = $m

})(window)
```

A brief edit: $m is intended to be an object with methods class and s.

And this is how it is referenced in a simple test page:

```
<h1 class="heading" onmouseover="$m(this).s.setAttribute('text-decoration', 'underline')" onmouseout="$m(this).s.setAttribute('text-decoration', 'none')">Testing.</h1>
```

Another edit: I have attempted to do this, and although it throws no errors it does not work correctly. I'm a bit stumped with what exactly is not being called.

Here is the new library:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    //set document to this local scope
    var document = window.document
    //create $m object
    var $m = function(obj) {
    //if it is anything but an element return itself
        if (typeof obj === "object") {
        return new init(obj);
        }
    //if it is an element return that element
        else {
        return new init(document.getElementById(obj));
        }
    }

    function init(elem){
        //set properties
        this.elem = elem;
    }

    init.prototype = {
        //return style
        sty: function() {
            return this.elem.style;
        },

            //return all objects with a certain class

        cla: function() {
        var allelem = document.getElementsByTagName('*')
        var give = []

        //gather all elements in the document and get those with matching class
            for (var q = 0 ; q < allelem.length ; ++q){
        if (allelem[q].className === this.elem.className){
            give.push(allelem[q]);
        }
        }
        //return found elements
        return give;
    }
    }
    //expose $m to global scope
    window.$m = $m;
})(window)
```

and an attempt to fix how it is referenced:

```
<h1 class="heading" id="test" onmouseover="$m(this).sty.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="$m(this).sty.textDecoration='none'">Testing.</h1>
```

Comment: Use a) indentation b) more semicolons

Comment: Your syntax is simply invalid. I'd suggest learning more of the basics before creating a library.

Comment: @user1689607: Apart from the missing brace and the use of a reserved word, it is valid code.

Comment: @Bergi: Sure, apart from the invalid stuff, it's valid. :P But the use of `class:` is actually valid code, but some older browsers don't like it.

Comment: @user1689607: Depends on where you use it. Not as a label identifier, I'd say :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I just meant as a property name. Very true that the syntax is invalid as a statement label.

Comment: @Bergi: Even taking `class:` and `s:` as labels (and ignoring the reserved word issue) it would still be invalid because you can't have anonymous function statements.

Comment: Regarding your edit: is `$m` supposed to *be* "an object with methods class and s" or is it supposed to *return* such an object?

Comment: I'd advise you to watch the hubris.  Learn to walk before you run.  A new JS programmer is not going to reinvent jQuery, any more than a first-time musician is gonna play like Hendrix or a first-time carpenter is going to build a personal copy of the White House.  People build up to that kind of complexity.

Comment: @cHao: Please tell me you're not equating jQuery with Hendrix! jQuery's more like C.C. Deville. ;-)

Comment: As far as I can understand it, your `class` function is nearly equivalent to `document.getElementsByClassName` and there's no reason anyway for it to be part of a big complex object. A library can be just a list of functions that are usually useful and that's probably the best way to start.

Comment: @user1689607: :)  My point is, it's not shameful to start small.  In fact, it's a *good* thing.  There's very little more damaging to one's ego than failing miserably at a project.  The only thing i can think of, actually, is *succeeding* miserably.

Comment: @cHao there's no harm, however, in trying to figure out how someone has implemented something by trying it out themselves. I doubt the OP is planning on taking over the world with this, but if you never try to copy Hendrix you'll never play like him.

Comment: @cHao: Yeah, I understood, and agree. :)

Comment: @cHao - The OP _is_ starting small: the question says "This is the library itself", that is, the code shown is the _whole_ library. But once he or she gets the syntax and structure right for that code it becomes relatively easy to add additional methods.

Comment: I only just noticed the edit you made - did you get it sorted, or is it still not working? From the HTML in your edit you need to add `()` after `sty` in order to call the function (otherwise your modifying properties of the `sty` function - not what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong here.
First, as user1689607 says, your syntax is invalid; you want (I think) the following for the last part:

```
function class(name){
    var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('*')
    var objects = []

    for (var q = 0 ; q < ele.length ; ++q){
        if (ele[q].className === name){
            objects.push(ele[q])
        }
    }
    return objects
}

function s() {
    return this.style
}
```

This still won't work, though, since `class` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Furthermore, your code from further up isn't going to allow you to do what you're trying to do in your HTML. What you're looking for is to create a new object containing the parameter you pass to `$` as a field, with the functions you've defined as members.

Try the following:

```
function MyObjConstructor(param) {
    this.field = param;
}

MyObjConstructor.prototype = 
{
    s:function(){...}//As your S function, but replace "this" with "this.field"
    clazz:function(){...}//As your class function, but replace "this" with "this.field"
}
```

and finally

```
function $m(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === "object") {
        return new MyObjConstructor(obj);
    }
    else {
        return new MyObjConstructor(document.getElementById(obj));
    }
}
```

This results in each object that is passed to your `$` function being wrapped, and exposing the appropriate methods. I'm not sure how jQuery does it, but this is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
class: function(name){ … }

s: function(){ … }
```

I don't know what you expect those statements to do. Usually, something like this appears in an object literal, but in here you just have [labeled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Also, you are missing a closing brace somewhere.

From your usage, it seems you want them to be properties of the returned object. As you return a plain DOM element, you would need to extend them with those custom properties:

```
var el = document.getElementById(obj);
el["class"] = function(name){ … }; // notice that "class" is a reserved word,
//                           you should not use it as a (property) identifier
el.s = function(name){ … }; // notice this defines a /function/,
//                   which you still had to invoke - you can't just use ".s…"
return el;
```

This is generally [considered bad practice](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/), and you won't rejoice in it. Read the article for better patterns.

Btw, `style` declarations have no `setAttribute` method as DOM elements have. You can either directly assign to a property, or use the [`setProperty` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration).

Also, the `s` or `sty` property is a function. You will need to call it before you can access the style declaration object: `$m(this).sty().textDecoration = …`; "getStyle" might be a more appropriate name.